# How to use handlebars 'if' with emberjs model data

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Iam having a table using bootstrap components with each row clickable
am also using handlebars inside table rows

```
<tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">

 {{#each model.pastreqlist}}

{{#if_eq {{status}} "PENDING"}} 

<tr  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pastreq {{action "selectRow" this target="view"}}">

{{else}}

<tr>  

{{/if_eq}}
        <td>{{employee_name}}</td>
        <td>{{type_id}}</td>
        <td>{{from_date}}</td>
       </tr>
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
```

i want to enable the content inside tr i.e i want to pop up modal for only those rows which is having status as "PENDING"

so far i have tried this but its not working

here's my helper code also

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
if(a == b)
    return opts.fn(this);
else
    return opts.inverse(this);
});
```

here is my controller code

```
App.LinksController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    myleavesinfolist: function () {
      rdata = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myleaves",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
      }).responseJSON;
      this.transitionToRoute("myleaves", rdata);
    } //myleavesinfolist
  } //actions
}); //controller
```

please help am a newbie to handlebars and ember js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used handlebars registerhelper in my script as below

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifeq', function(a, b, options) {
  return Ember.Handlebars.bind.call(options.contexts[0], a, options, true,     function(result) {
    return result === b;
  });
});
```

and in my template i have done like this

```
      {{#each model.pastreqlist}}
        {{#ifeq status "PENDING"}}
          <tr  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pastrequestsmodal" {{action "selectRow" this target="view"}} style="cursor: pointer">
        {{else}}
          <tr>
        {{/ifeq}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set up a computer property on your model, like this:

```
App.Request = Ember.Model.extend({
    stats:DS.attr('string'),
    isPending:function(){
        if(this.get('status') === 'PENDING'){
            return true;
        }
    }.property('status')
});
```

Then in your template, you can do it like this:

```
<tbody data-link="row" class="rowlink">
    {{#each model.pastreqlist}}
        {{#if isPending}} 
            <tr  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pastreq" {{action "selectRow" this target="view"}}>
        {{else}}
            <tr>  
        {{/if}}
            <td>{{employee_name}}</td>
            <td>{{type_id}}</td>
            <td>{{from_date}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Comment: it is not working  i have added my controller code in the above question. just to make you also know that am not using any routes in my application, tjhe entire table data is coming from the controlller which gets data from server.. please review once and advice me.@NicholasJohn16